# Calculations on datetime range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem with calculation on datetime fields.
I have two variables:

```
a = Sat, 01 Feb 2014 13:00:00 CET +01:00
```

and

```
b = Fri, 28 Feb 2014 13:00:00 CET +01:00
```

And I want to calculate how many days passed from a to b range.
Please Help.

Comment: Have you tried (a..b) ?

Comment: Define when a day passes. Is it when the range overlaps the moment of the midnight of that day? Is it when the range overlaps with any moment of the day? Is it when the range overlaps from the beginning of the day till the end? etc.

Comment: You mean the difference between those two dates,i.e, a-b?

Comment: Yeah exactly, I now try some examples and I think that a-b will be solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this.

```
require 'date'
( Date.parse('Fri, 28 Feb 2014 13:00:00 CET +01:00') - Date.parse('Sat, 01 Feb 2014 13:00:00 CET +01:00')).to_i
=> 27
i.e
 ( Date.parse(b) - Date.parse(a)).to_i
```

Comment: This is what I about to answer,but you got it first. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'date'


a=Date.parse('Sat, 01 Feb 2014 13:00:00 CET +01:00')
 => #<Date: 2014-02-01 (4913379/2,0,2299161)> 



 b=Date.parse('Fri, 28 Feb 2014 13:00:00 CET +01:00')
 => #<Date: 2014-02-28 (4913433/2,0,2299161)> 

b-a
 => (27/1) 

(b-a).to_i
 => 27
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **time_diff gem** to calculate the difference.

In your gem file add `gem 'time_diff'`

I have added the code in index.html.erb but, you can use it any where you want.

take a look on following code.

```
<% require 'time_diff' %>

<% a = Time.diff(Time.parse('Sat, 01 Feb 2014 13:00:00 CET +01:00'), Time.parse('Fri, 28 Feb 2014 13:00:00 CET +01:00'), "%d") %>
<%= a[:diff] %>
```

and I got the following result

**"27 days"**

You can also take a look on
https://github.com/abhidsm/time_diff